# Retrofit get the last request of multiple requests

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an a recycler view with items in it. When i click at an item i make an api call to get some data to attach it in another recycler view the problem is when the user click multiple times in items in the recycler it make many api requests and return the last and i only care about the last clicked item request and i want to cancel the rest of the requests and ignore them i try ti use a timer but it's failed

there is my current code

```
 @Override
    public void onSelectedSourceClick(SelectedSource selectedSource, int position) {
        newsAdapter.clearNewsList();

        okHttpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll();

        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(500, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
//Make the request here
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

But this solution does't work actually so if any one has solution or using RxJava for it.

Comment: Use Retrofit 2's Call class to form your network request which also allows to cancel it. Use a data  structure (like Stack) to keep the list of added call objects and check it everytime the list item is clicked and a new request has to be created.
How to cancel request - https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests
There may be Rx way also but don't know about it as of now

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar. Here's how I achieved this using Retrofit + RxJava

create `CompositeSubscription`

```
private CompositeSubscription mSearchPlaceSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
```

Now you before calling API & Subscribing to new API call, I do

```
mSearchPlaceSubscription.clear();
```

That step will result into unsubscribing from previous requests & hence `RxJavaCallAdapter` will ask okhttp client to cancel the request.

& then I call API by this way:

```
mSearchPlaceSubscription.add(mSearchPlacesHelper.searchPlaces(query)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Prediction>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Prediction> predictions) {
                        setChanged();
                        notifyObservers(predictions);
                    }
                }));
```

here

`mSearchPlacesHelper.searchPlaces(query)` returns the `Observable` to which I `subscribe`(which returns `Subscription`). I do all this code inside
`mSearchPlaceSubscription.add()` which accepts Subscription object.

so my final API call looks like:

```
mSearchPlaceSubscription.clear();
mSearchPlaceSubscription.add(mSearchPlacesHelper.searchPlaces(query)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Prediction>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Prediction> predictions) {

                    }
                }));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i using live data factory to return a live data object instead of call so i can't return a obseravble from it

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get by live data object. Do you mean LiveData from Architecture Components?

Comment: yes i using a custom factory to get a LiveData object instead  of call object

Comment: I have not used LiveData yet, but you could try something similar. store LiveData object & Observer which you pass in observe() globally & before calling again liveData.observe(myObserver), you should do liveData.removeObserver(myObserver). & then re-initialize myObserver = new Observer() & then pass it to liveData.observe(myObserver),

Comment: the observer is activity it self LifeCycleOwner

Comment: i change the live data to use `Observable ` and it's work after some modification nut your solution is for Rxjava1 i done mine using Rxjava2 but think you for this idea

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by cancelling all pending requests when a new request is made.
Like if you pressed two items then when you are making 2nd request,cancel all pending requests using this piece of code.

`client.dispatcher().cancelAll()`

Hope this helps you.